# Map hasn`t been displayed

Tags: iphone, sdk

please i have a problem with Map displaying, although, in the simulator it`s displayed well, on the iPhone i see this (the left one is with **Hybrid** mode and the right is with **standard** mode):

[image]

here is some of my code :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    location = newLocation.coordinate;


    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    if (shouldAdjustZoom) {
        //use the manually defined span
        span.latitudeDelta=.005;
        span.longitudeDelta=.005;
        mapRegion.span = span;
    }
    else {
        mapRegion=mapView.region;
        mapRegion.center=newLocation.coordinate;
        mapView.region=mapRegion;
    }

    // Apply new coordinates
    [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated:TRUE];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue color actually makes me think you are in the middle of the ocean. Have you checked your center point?

Comment: Are you setting a default region somewhere else? I notice you aren't changing it if "shouldAdjustZoom" is true. Also, you'll want a default region in case a location hasn't come in yet.

Comment: Also, add this where you set the region: NSLog(@"%f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);